# Golang ambiguous err redefinition

Tags: go, definition

Why is it possible to *redefine* the `err` variable?

```
err := ipdf.Open(source)
if err != nil {
    panic("Couldn't open pdf.")
}

payload, err := ioutil.ReadFile(other)
if err != nil {
    panic("Couldn't read other file.")
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, as much as possible, using inline checks:

```
// local scope
if err := ipdf.Open(source); err != nil {
    panic("Couldn't open pdf.")
}

payload, err := ioutil.ReadFile(other)
if err != nil {
    panic("Couldn't read other file.")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Short variable declarations are used mainly when you have to declare variables for temporary use and those variable names can be used in the further program too. For example, "err" can be used anytime in the further program.
Lets assume the language was java, you would had to declare more different variable names for the further program.
But in golang, short variable declarations work as "let" in javascript. 
Hope this helps.