# "err declared but not used" with multiple errors

Tags: go, variables, error-handling, compiler-errors

If I have a program like this:

```
package main
import "strconv"

func main() {
   a, err := strconv.Atoi("100")
   println(a)
}
```

I get this result, as expected:

```
.\file.go:5:7: err declared but not used
```

However this program:

```
package main
import "strconv"

func main() {
   a, err := strconv.Atoi("100")
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   b, err := strconv.Atoi("100")
   println(a, b)
}
```

Compiles without error, even though I never checked the second `err` value. Why does this happen? Also, can I change some option, so that these mistakes result in compile time errors or warnings?

Comment: The second one is not a "declared but never used" error, but "assigned but never read" error, which, apparently, is not an error.  https://play.golang.org/p/dXHItC7QmTd

Comment: "reassignment" is described here in the spec for [Short Variable Declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations). While it's not an error, most static analysis tools will warn about this.

Comment: The questions are different, but have a similar answer: there isn't actually a new `err` variable.

Comment: @StevenPenny: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387743/golang-ambiguous-err-redefinition is the exact same issue, but since this one is expressed more clearly we can reopen it (though the answer in either case is really only to quote the spec, because it's just a tradeoff made in the language design)

Comment: Don't fight it - it's just the way Go is. If you don't like the ambiguity of an implicit declaration, especially when two variables are assigned - just pre-declare:  https://play.golang.org/p/oh3HJqH1eat  This avoid shadow assigns and other bugs associated with return variables.

Comment: Complaining about not getting an error isn't really something anyone can help you with. Per the language spec, it is not an error. There is no option to treat a non-error as an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in the second case you are re-using an existing `err` variable, so it is being used. Despite the `:=` instantiate & assign operator, a new `err` variable is not instantiated.

If you named the errors differently, such as this:

```
func main() {
   a, err := strconv.Atoi("100")
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   b, err2 := strconv.Atoi("100")
   println(a, b)
}
```

Then you would see a compile error for both cases.

If you don't want to change your code but also still want to be notified of this issue, you will need to rely on a go linter instead of the go compiler. Go has a very robust ecosystem of linters so I won't recommend one in particular, but at my organization I would see an error like this from our linter if I were to write such code:

```
scratch/test.go:10:2: ineffectual assignment to err (ineffassign)
           b, err := strconv.Atoi("100")
```